# My given time in expireAfterSeconds is not working in ttl. row is deleted by its own within minute

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

**here is my code...kindly review it.**
this automatically deletes the record without mentioning the seconds.
i changed the createindex to ensureindex also ...but still not working

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testing5";


var extend;
var time = "3600";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
    var dbase = db.db("testing5");
var myobj = ({
  "name": "Adnan khan",
   "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
   "createdAt": new Date(),
});


dbase.collection("log_events").createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: time })


  dbase.collection("log_events").insertOne(myobj, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    resultant = result

    console.log("data inserted and will be deleted approximately after 20 seconds");
    db.close();
  });
  });
```

Comment: did you try, getIndexes from shell to see what all indexes are there?

Comment: no...i didnt. will you guide me plz.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the ttl value as a number. So instead of writing

```
var time = "3600";
```

try writing

```
var time = 3600;
```

Also, kindly note that this is 3600 seconds so 1 hour and not 20 minutes...

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-after-a-specified-number-of-seconds

Comment: ok...I corrected it..but still the time which i put in this variable is not affecting that row.. the row is automatically deleted in first few second..

Comment: Then there's another TTL index left over which you will need to get rid of first: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/#view-existing-indexes